# Ubuntu pdftoppm converting pdf to png

Tags: 16.04, pdf, png

In `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, I use `pdftoppm` to convert `pdf` files to png files one by one like the code given below:

```
pdftoppm -rx 300 -ry 300 -png XYZ.pdf XYZ
```

However, I have to convert many pdf files to png files. I wonder if it is possible to convert many pdf files to png files with single command like

```
pdftoppm -rx 300 -ry 300 -png *.pdf *
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use simple `for` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.pdf; do
   pdftoppm -png -rx 300 -ry 300 $i ${i%.pdf*}
done
```

Comment: Thanks @EdiD for your answer. Do I need to use this command in Ubuntu Terminal?

Comment: @MYaseen208 This is a script. Make a file (in folder where your pdfs are located) with this content, give executive rights (`chmod u+x yourfile.sh`) for file and launch it in this way: `./yourfile.sh`

Comment: @MYaseen208 and yes off course this is executable from terminal

Comment: Thanks @EdiD for your useful answer.  First need to move the folder, `chmod a+x yourfile.sh` and  `./yourfile.sh` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: You can also copy this into a terminal and then press ENTER (after you cd into the directory).